# How can I generate all unique card pairs from a list of cards?

Tags: java, data-structures, poker

I am implementing a hand strength evaluator, which is to evaluate all possible
pairs from the remaining 47 cards, after dealing one hand and the flop.

I have implemented the evaluator, but I'm missing all the possible combinations for which to compare. I am tempted to create a class for Hand, which consists of two cards, and store each combination in a set, HashSet. Which data structure should i choose? If HashSet is best,
then how can i force each instantiation of Hand to be unique?

Comment: If you number your cards 0..51, you need only 52 bits to represent any subset of cards. Hence, a `long` with its 64 bits is sufficient. A set of all pairs would then be a hash set of `long`s, with two bits set (one for each card number from the pair).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HashSet` seems reasonable although since ordering might matter later you might want to consider a `TreeSet`. If you implements the `equals` and `compareTo`/`Comparable` methods in `Hand` the `Set` will force uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

I would number the cards or place them in a List.

If you use a list you can do

```
Set<Card> inHand = ...
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
  Card card1 = list.get(i);
  if (inHand.contains(card1)) continue;

  for(int j=i+1;j<list.size();j++) {
      Card card2 = list.get(j);
      if (inHand.contains(card2)) continue;

      // process card1 and card2
```